# $\mathbb{Q}$ is totally disconnected w.r.t. natural metric

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness

Let $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $C(x)$ be the connected component of $x$ in $\mathbb{Q}$. We want to show that $C(x)-\{x\}=\emptyset$. (I.e. that $\mathbb{Q}$ is totally disconnected.)

Assume $y\in C(x)-\{x\}$. There exists a connected set $F\subset\mathbb{Q}$ such that $x\in F$,  $y\in F$ and $x\ne y$. WLOG take $x<y$. Then there exists $\xi\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ such that $x<\xi<y$. Is there a way to use $\xi$ to deduce that $F$ is not connected contrary to assumption?

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}\cap (-\infty,\xi)$ and $\mathbb{Q}\cap (\xi,+\infty)$ decomposes $F$ into two nonempty, disjoint and open subsets.

Comment: Yes that works thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Just consider the map$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&F&\longrightarrow&\Bbb R\\&a&\mapsto&\begin{cases}0&\text{ if }a<\xi\\1&\text{ if }a>\xi.\end{cases}\end{array}$$Then $f(F)=\{0,1\}$, which is impossible, since $F$ is connected and $f$ is continuous.